In OAuth 2.0, does the resource server need to add authorization logic based on user attributes?
Lets take a GitHub OAuth app.
The client goes through the authorization code flow to get an access token to GitHub.
The client sends the access token to GitHub's resource server (https://api.github.com/)
How does the resource server determine that I can access my private repositories, but not a different user's repositories?
Does it take a user_id field from the decoded access token and then add some logic to determine if access should be granted?
If this is the case, it feels like OAuth is not doing any authorization at all, the resource server still needs to know who is trying to access the resource and add some custom logic to determine if  access should be granted or not.
My concern is that usually authorization is a granular decision based on several fields. And the best OAuth can do is give you some granularity based on scopes, but it is not as granular as understanding what roles a user may have or what groups he may belong to or even what company they belong to.
Shouldn't the final decision of authorization be done by the resource server based on the resource owner's attributes? If so, what is the point of OAuth and why are we not sending user attribute information directly.

OAuth scopes contain claims and you should be able to issue claims like these to an access token that your resource servers (APIs) uses for authorization:

customer_id
company_id
country_code
roles
subscription_level

These values are then delivered securely to APIs in a verifiable JWT access token. The access token can be sent from any type of client. If you put these values in HTTP headers or path segments a malicious party might alter them to cause exploits.
The authorization server issues access tokens and can include values that an API cannot work out for itself. For example, a level_of_assurance claim can inform APIs of the authentication strength with which the user signed in.
The resource server is responsible for applying authorization and can use additional user attributes when doing so. Eg it might look up extra values from a customer_id or role claim. Generally you don't put every single value needed for authorization in access tokens.
For example, a GitHub API might only need to receive a user identity claim and scopes the user has granted. It can then use the user ID to filter allowed resources. But the repository details do not need to be in the token.
